# Get <td> text using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<html>
<body>
<table style="border:0">
<tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="pr10">Mon</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="pr10">Tue</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bold">
            <td class="pr10">Wed</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="pr10">Thu</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="pr10">Fri</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="pr10">Sat</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="pr10">Sun</td>
            <td class="pl10">11am – 11pm</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
</body>
```

Try 1:
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='pr10']")

Try 2:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td='Mon']/td").text

But it not fetching the text "Mon" "11am - 11pm"

```
text_area = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='pr10']")    
for items2 in text_area:    
print(items2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
text_area = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="body"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]""")
print([elm.get_attribute('innerHTML') for elm in text_area])
```

Comment: It's return empty array []

Comment: give id "body" to your body tag

Comment: elm.get_attribute('innerHTML') i get the text thanks for your support